# Who had Neville seen die?

Tags: harry-potter

In ***Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix***

> When Hagrid introduces the Gryffindors and Slytherins to thestrals only 3 students are able to see them, as people can't see them unless they have witnessed death. Harry had witnessed Cedric's death at the hands of Voldemort.

Another student was Neville.

> I know Neville's parents weren't killed by the Death Eaters, but "only" driven insane.  I can't remember Neville seeing anyone else die.  So, who did he see die (or was it never revealed)?

It seems safe to assume the third student was just someone JKR threw in.

> That's because it would be unlikely to have that many students who hadn't seen death by that time in life.

Comment: It would  be nice if the downvoters would say why they are downvoting. As I said in a response to the answer, I haven't yet read the books, don't remember this from the movie, and overheard this small part of the story as a mother read it to her son.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

His grandfather:

> Professor Umbridge smiled indulgently at them and then turned to Neville.
>
> 'You can see the Thestrals, Longbottom, can you?' she said.
>
> Neville nodded.
>
> 'Who did you see die?' she asked, her tone indifferent.
>
> 'My...my grandad,' said Neville.
>
> <sup><sub>*Harry Potter and the Order of the Phoenix* Chapter 21: "The Eye of the Snake"</sub></sup>

Comment: Thanks. I don't remember this from the movies (not sure if it was there or if I forgot) and haven't (yet) read the books. I overheard a mother reading part of that bit to her son, but didn't hear the whole thing and it was bothering me.

Comment: I don't think it's ever mentioned in the movies FYI, IIRC all the members of DA who travel to the Ministry can all magically see the Thestrals in the movies, much more comical situation in the books :).

Comment: @CandiedMango - Technically, any student who was at the Triwizard tournament when Harry returned with Cedric's body should be able to see the thestrals.